# How to install Ecobee thermostat to central heat pump (two wires)

Tags: electrical, wiring, thermostat, heating

I am trying to install an Ecobee Enhanced thermostat to my central heat pump which I am told has 1 stage of heating, cooling, and aux heat and has an inverter which ramps up and down. However, the current wiring on the thermostat that came with the system only has two wires, as pictured. Ecobee is stating I'll need more to leverage the new thermostat. Is anyone able to tell me which wires should go where? I already had an electrician come in and try, but after two hours he left without resolution. I tried calling a large HVAC company in my town and they said they can't do it either.

I've also added some photos of the manual I found which should help I hope as well as a photo of wiring from Ecobee they sent.

[image: TSTAT]

[image: PUMP]

[image: TSTATNEW]

[image: MODEL]

[image: ECOBEE]

[image: P1]

[image: P2]

[image: P3]

[image: P4]

Comment: so you have all the wires at the thermostat and just need them connected to the ecobee properly, or you have 10 wires at the ecobee and haven't connected them to the ecobee or the airhandler/heat pump?

Comment: @FreshCodemonger, apologies, I should’ve clarified. They are not attached at either end. I’ve worked with Ecobee support for hours and they could not help. They said two wires is not normal.

Comment: I agree that two wires is not normal for a heating and cooling system. Also, the normal 24 volt interface (terminal strip) on the furnace doesn't seem to be connected. Can you add a photo of the front of the current thermostat?

Comment: 2 wires just means you were only previously setup for heat and that the thermo either required no power or was battery powered.  it is hard to tell from your pic on the heat pump - what are white and black currently hooked up to?

Comment: you have a 1H1C ( one heating and one cooling stage ) so you should be looking at 1h1c wiring.   are your indoor and outdoor units wired together it seems like they should be but your picture shows nothing hooked up?

Comment: @Zach -- have you run the new cable I mentioned in my [prior answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/287107/27099) yet, or does your existing cable already have the necessary wires in it?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, as mentioned above, I had the wires pulled through and an electrician tried to install them, but was not successful. I called an HVAC company and they said they couldn’t do it.